# google script: web app link cannot open in other browser

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

after I deployed as web app  and set for anyone and anonymous

(the end of the link is already set as "exec")

My friend who use google chrome can use it regularly.

but those who use other browser such as in from line , Microsoft edge cannot use

it shows sorry cannot open file at this time with google drive logo.

is there any solution help me sole this trouble from my side
(not to ask those people to change setting)

Comment: "it shows sorry cannot open file at this time with google drive logo." Check your user and access.  Check your login account.  Open in incognito mode , log in .

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Most likely, those who are trying to open in Edge are signed in to several Google accounts. If so, then let them try to log out of all accounts and log in again.